# Does wijmo have a detail template like kendo?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, wijmo

I've been looking around it seems wijmo has a lot more for me to work with, as is the documentation much better than kendo.  However, i can't seem to find an equivalent of the kendo detail template with wijmo.

Perhaps some wijmo experts could lead me in the direction of doing the equivalent of this
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/detailtemplate.html

with wijmo. :)

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box this is not a default feature, however you could achieve the same functionality with the templating feature of the data grid.